# $\left(\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2$ = 18 why??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I would like to now why

$$\left(\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2$$

is equal to $18$? Please provide me
the proccess. Thank you.

Comment: $(a+b)^2 =  \, ?$

Comment: I would like to see another 8 (almost) identical answers to this problem! :)

Comment: @mathse Not quite - there are two methods, with $3+5=8$.

Comment: @user1729PhD Two methods - 4 proofs each - or rather it is 5-to-3 concurrently (but still counting) :)

Comment: Hint: $\,\sqrt 8\, =\, 2\sqrt 2\ \ $

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{16} = 4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ (\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{2})^2 = (\sqrt{8})^2+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{8}+(\sqrt{2})^2=8+2\sqrt{2\cdot 8}+2 = 10 + 2 \cdot 4 = 18$$

Comment: Factoring out $\sqrt2$ first is simpler.

Comment: The only answer with no upvotes is the accepted answer! No upvotes from me, I agree with Yves.

Comment: @M.Vinay I was surprised too.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree with you, however this method has the advantage to be "more general", e.g. factoring anything in $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^2$ will be less elegant... But it is not rare that the method which is the most elegant get the most of upvotes but is not the method which is accepted (isn't it?).

Comment: @Surb Eh? I didn't! Your answer had $0$ votes from the first time I saw it. I rarely downvote answers - even slightly wrong ones (that can be corrected).

Comment: @M.Vinay Sorry, I just saw -2 in my rep today (because of this post) that's why I thought it was you and didn't got the point.

Answer (score 19):

$$\left(\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2=\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2=\left(3\sqrt{2}\right)^2=9\times2=18$$

Comment: ... $= 9\cdot 2 = 18$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{2}&=2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\\
&=(2+1)\sqrt{2}\\
&=3\sqrt{2}
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\left(\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2=???$$

Answer (score 6):

Take out the common factor of $\sqrt2$.
$$
\begin{align*}
(\sqrt8+\sqrt2)^2
&=(2\sqrt2+\sqrt2)^2\\
&=\sqrt2^2(2+1)^2\\
&=2\times3^2\\
&=\cdots\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment on how I can improve my post?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I would assume that the downvoter meant to say that this problem is way too simple to deserve 8 eight answers (5+3 of which are identical) ...

Comment: Although I wouldn't disagree that $8$ answers is overkill, not all of the answers were downvoted when I posted this comment (and they all still are not). Also, in my defence, noone else had this method when I posted it (or, at least, started typing it...)!

Comment: Yes, 2 answers are not yet downvoted. If you wish I can do this job for you, so there is at least some equality here :) But I will surely not upvote any of the answers :)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter either, but my guess is that you weren't condescending enough. Maybe you needed to imply that the OP is incapable of even the simplest arithmetic.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{8 \cdot 2} = \sqrt{16} = 4$.

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly is wrong about it? My impression was that the OP has a problem with the second term in the expansion. It's obvious that squares of $\sqrt{8}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are $8$ and $2$, so I gave a hint about the second term: $2 \sqrt{8 \cdot 2} = 2 \cdot 4$ leaving the OP to get the $2$ in front.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I'll delete my comment. I thought the $\cdot$ was a $+$.

Comment: ...and the downvote :)

Comment: I prefer commenting rather than downvoting :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$

Answer (score 3):

It does look counter-intuitive, doesn't it? But if you step through the multiplication, I think it will become crystal clear to you. First of all, $$(\sqrt{8} + \sqrt{2})^2 = (\sqrt{8} + \sqrt{2})(\sqrt{8} + \sqrt{2})$$, right? Applying FOIL (First, Outer, Inner, Last), we get $$\sqrt{8} \sqrt{8} = 8$$ $$\sqrt{8} \sqrt{2} = 4$$ $$\sqrt{2} \sqrt{8} = 4$$ $$\sqrt{2} \sqrt{2} = 2$$ And then $8 + 4 + 4 + 2 = 18$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$$
(a+b)^2=(\color{red}a+\color{blue}b)(a+b)=\color{red}a(a+b)+\color{blue}b(a+b)=a^2+2ab+b^2.
$$